# SQL Server multiple table join and update value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 Tables in MS SQL that I am trying to join:

**Table 1:**

```
CFG   Part  Commodity
---------------------
CFG1  PN1    Com1
CFG1  PN2    Com1
CFG1  PN3    Com1
CFG2  PN4    Com2
```

**Table 2:**

```
Part   Site     Product
-----------------------
PN1    Site1     Prod1
PN1    Site1     Prod2
PN1    Site2     Prod1
PN4    Site1     Prod1
```

**Table3:**

```
Product  Family  LOB
--------------------
Prod1    Fam1    LOB1
Prod2    Fam2    LOB1
```

I am using the following query to join these 3 tables:-

```
select distinct b.CFG, a.Part, b.Commodity, a.Site,   c.Family, 
c.LOB, c.Product 
from Table_2 a, Table_1 b, Table_3 c
where b.Part = a.Part and c.Product = a.Product
```

This is the outcome I am getting:-

```
CFG     Part    Commodity   Site    Family  LOB     Product
-----------------------------------------------------------
CFG1    PN1     Com1        Site1   Fam1    LOB1    Prod1
CFG1    PN1     Com1        Site1   Fam2    LOB2    Prod2
CFG1    PN1     Com1        Site2   Fam1    LOB1    Prod1
CFG2    PN4     Com2        Site1   Fam1    LOB1    Prod1
```

This is all good but the part should translate all the values back to the CFG and all the other parts under that CFG. For example, the values of PN1 should be translated to CFG1 and in turn to PN2 and PN3. This is how I would like to see the outcome:-

```
 CFG        Part    Commodity   Site    Family  LOB     Product
-----------------------------------------------------------
CFG1    PN1     Com1        Site1   Fam1    LOB1    Prod1
CFG1    PN2     Com1        Site1   Fam1    LOB1    Prod1
CFG1    PN3     Com1        Site1   Fam1    LOB1    Prod1
CFG1    PN1     Com1        Site1   Fam2    LOB2    Prod2
CFG1    PN2     Com1        Site1   Fam2    LOB2    Prod2
CFG1    PN3     Com1        Site1   Fam2    LOB2    Prod2
CFG1    PN1     Com1        Site2   Fam1    LOB1    Prod1
CFG1    PN2     Com1        Site2   Fam1    LOB1    Prod1
CFG1    PN3     Com1        Site2   Fam1    LOB1    Prod1
CFG2    PN4     Com2        Site1   Fam1    LOB1    Prod1
```

Have spent a lot of time thinking how it could be done and finally seeking your help.

Comment: it would be easier if you tell us what you're trying to answer, instead of having us trying to relate your tables to the expected output.

Comment: PN2 Doesn't exist in Table2. so where would the values come to your result?

Comment: @JamesZ Yes that is true that PN2 does not exist in Table2 but since in Table 1 PN1, PN2 and PN3 all lie within CFG1, the attributes of PN1 should translate to PN2 and PN3. This is the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: @AbhishekDahiya Well that was not described in your question at all. For the future, if you have things like that, it should be definitely written there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is crazy, but try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.CFG, a.Part, a.Commodity, b.Site
    , c.Family, c.LOB, c.Product 
FROM Table_1 as a
CROSS JOIN Table_2 as b 
INNER JOIN Table_3 as c ON c.Product = b.Product
WHERE b.Part in (SELECT Part FROM Table_1 as t WHERE t.CFG = a.CFG)
ORDER BY a.CFG, c.Family, b.Site
```